# Inline image loading..webpack

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am pulling my hair off...

Feels like I have tried everything.

This is my webpack config:

```
    var publicConfig = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000',
    './public.jsx',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
    filename: 'publicBundle.js',
    publicPath: '/assets/',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
        //{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' },
        // { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]' },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
          loader: 'url?limit=25000'
        },
        { test   : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/, loader : 'file-loader' } 
    ] 
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

When defining images in my css files the images gets added to the /assets/ folder, which is exactly what I want... However, I want to be able to call image paths from inline ( the html views aswell ). But the images doesnt get copied to /assets/ unless I target them from my css file.

I tried importing them by:

```
import logo from './images/animus_logo_blacktext.png'
```

But it still doesnt appear in my assets.

What is the best practice for image paths inline?

Comment: How do you target them from CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the images are very small? The limit you configured in URL-loader means that all images under 25000 bytes will be inlined (as data URI's) instead of served as a file. Files larger than 25000 bytes will be treated by url-loader the same way file-loader treats them.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to try https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin.  This is a webpack plugin that copies individual files or entire directories to the build directory.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to the file-loader instead of the url loader.  The images may be under your limit of 25000 (25kb).

Without modifying your webpack configuration you could try this:

```
import logo from 'file-loader!./images/animus_logo_blacktext.png'
```

You should see the image in your assets.